# Nginx question mark in location move to another location

Tags: nginx

Greeting!

I have a problem with my nginx location construction:

```
location /expert/chat/ {
    proxy_buffering off;
    if ($http_cookie !~* "auth.local.mysite") {
        return 301 /account/login?ReturnUrl=%2Fexpert%2Fchat;
    }
    proxy_pass http://expert-chat:3005/expert/;
}
```

It work as it should, but now I need to make this `/expert/chat/?admin` to return to `/account/login?ReturnUrl=%2Fexpert%2Fchat%2F%3Fadmin` (add /?admin to ReturnUrl).

How should I make this?

UPD:

If I add this

```
if ($request_uri ~ '\?admin') {
    return 301 /account/login?ReturnUrl=%2Fexpert%2Fchat%2F%3Fadmin;
}
```

moving works, but it moves me anyway have I cookie or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`map`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html) substitution block (should be placed **outside** the `server` block):

```
map $args $url {
    ~(^|&)admin  /account/login?ReturnUrl=%2Fexpert%2Fchat%2F%3Fadmin;
    default      /account/login?ReturnUrl=%2Fexpert%2Fchat;
}

server {
    ...
    location /expert/chat/ {
        proxy_buffering off;
        if ($http_cookie !~* "auth.local.mysite") {
            return 301 $url;
        }
        proxy_pass http://expert-chat:3005/expert/;
    }
    ...
}
```